# Stop livestream when nobody is in the voice channel and play when a person joins discord.js

Tags: stream, discord.js, bots, live-streaming, ytdl

cloned a `GitHub project` and wanted to modify it a bit. The `bot` basically plays a `Youtube livestream` in a `voice channel` 24/7. I wanted to make it that the `bot` stops playing when nobody is in the `voice channel` and start as soon as a member joins the `voice channel`. Due to having zero knowledge in `discord.js`, I find it very difficult to accomplish my goal.

**Here's the following `code` used:**

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const keepAlive = require('./server.js');
 
const client = new Client({
  disableEveryone: true
});
 
keepAlive();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);

const { TOKEN, CHANNEL, STATUS, LIVE } = require("./config.json");
const discord = require("discord.js");
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
let broadcast = null;
let interval = null;



if (!TOKEN) {
  console.error("Press provide a valid Discord Bot Token.");
  return process.exit(1);
} else if (!CHANNEL || Number(CHANNEL) == NaN) {
  console.log("Please provide a valid channel ID.");
  return process.exit(1);
} else if (!LIVE) {
  console.log("Please provide a valid Youtube URL.");
  return process.exit(1);
}
client.on('ready', async () => {
  client.user.setActivity(STATUS, { type: "STREAMING", url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Igipt9XegCs"});
  let channel = client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL) || await client.channels.fetch(CHANNEL)

  if (!channel) {
    console.error("The provided channel ID doesn't exist, or I don't have permission to view that channel. Because of that, I'm aborting now.");
    return process.exit(1);
  } else if (channel.type !== "voice") {
    console.error("The provided channel ID is NOT voice channel. Because of that, I'm aborting now.");
    return process.exit(1);
  }
  broadcast = client.voice.createBroadcast();
  // Play the radio
  stream = await ytdl(LIVE);
  stream.on('error', console.error);
  broadcast.play(stream);
  // Make interval so radio will automatically reconnect to YT every 30 minute because YT will change the raw url every 30m/1 Hour
  
  const GuildMember = new Discord.GuildMember(); // This shall be the command author.



  if (!interval) {
    interval = setInterval(async function() {
      try {
       stream = await ytdl(LIVE, { highWaterMark: 100 << 150 });
       stream.on('error', console.error);
       broadcast.play(stream);
      } catch (e) { return }
    }, 1800000)
  }
  try {
    const connection = await channel.join();
    connection.play(broadcast);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

setInterval(async function() {
  if(!client.voice.connections.size) {
    let channel = client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL) || await client.channels.fetch(CHANNEL);
    if(!channel) return;
    try { 
      const connection = await channel.join();
      connection.play(broadcast);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}, 20000);

client.login(TOKEN) //Login

process.on('unhandledRejection', console.error);
```

I already tried using `voiceStateUpdate`, but I think I did many mistakes:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {

  if (oldState.channelID !==  oldState.guild.me.voice.channelID || newState.channel)
    return;


  if (!oldState.channel.members.size - 1) 
    setTimeout(() => { 
      if (!oldState.channel.members.size - 1) //  1 member, 
        broadcast.exit();
     }, 5000); 
});
```

Any help is appreciated.